# Ошибка призаписи в xml файл Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)

Tags: python, xml, xmlparser

У меня есть 5 xml файлов, в каждом по 1166 товаров, я их объединяю в один список в нём получается 8532 элементов, когда начинаю запускать, на записи в файл выдаёт ошибку после 1184 элемента

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)
```

Мой код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(30000)

def open_file_parse(name_file):
    with open(name_file, "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        content = f.readlines()
        content = "".join(content)
        xml = bs(content, "lxml")
        all_offers = xml.find_all('offer')
        offers = []
        x = 0
        for offer in all_offers:
            offer_id = offer['id']
            offer_manager = offer.find('managername').text
            offer_phone = offer.find('phone').text
            offer_addres = offer.find('address').text
            offer_cat_id = offer.find('youlacategoryid').text
            offer_sub_cat_id = offer.find('youlasubcategoryid').text
            offer_name = offer.find('name').text
            offer_desc = offer.find('description')
            offer_price = str(offer.find('price'))
            offer_picture = offer.find_all('picture')
            picture = [str(obj) for obj in offer_picture]
            context = {
                'id': offer_id,
                'manager': offer_manager,
                'phone': offer_phone,
                'addres': offer_addres,
                'cat': offer_cat_id,
                'sub_cat': offer_sub_cat_id,
                'name': offer_name,
                'desc': offer_desc,
                'price': offer_price,
                'picture': picture,
            }
            offers.append(context)
            x += 1
            print(f'обработано: {x}')

        f.close()
        print(f'Файл {name_file} обработан, {len(offers)} объявлений')
        return offers

def save_list_py(offers, file):
    with open(file, "a", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(f'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n'
                f'<yml_catalog date="2022-10-13 11:58">\n'
                f'<shop>\n<offers>\n')
        x = 0
        for offer in offers:
            f.write(f'<offer id="{offer.get("id")}">\n'
                    f'<managerName>{offer.get("manager")}</managerName>\n'
                    f'<phone>{offer.get("phone")}</phone>\n'
                    f'<address>{offer.get("addres")}</address>\n'
                    f'<youlaCategoryId>{offer.get("cat")}</youlaCategoryId>\n'
                    f'<youlaSubCategoryId>{offer.get("sub_cat")}</youlaSubCategoryId>\n'
                    f'<name>{offer.get("name")}</name>\n'
                    f'{str(offer.get("desc"))}\n'
                    f'{offer.get("price")}\n'
                    f'{"".join(offer.get("picture"))}\n')
            x += 1
            print(f'offer: {x}')
        
        f.write(f'</offers>\n</shop>\n</yml_catalog>')
        f.close()
    return print('good')

def unite_offers(tumen, ekat, kurgan, magnitka, chelab):
    offers = []
    while True:
        if len(tumen) > 0 or len(ekat) > 0 or len(kurgan) > 0 or len(magnitka) > 0 or len(chelab) > 0:
            if len(tumen) > 0:
                offers.append(tumen[0])
                tumen.pop(0)
                print(f'Т осталось {len(tumen)}')
            if len(ekat) > 0:
                offers.append(ekat[0])
                ekat.pop(0)
                print(f'E осталось {len(ekat)}')
            if len(kurgan) > 0:
                offers.append(kurgan[0])
                kurgan.pop(0)
                print(f'K осталось {len(kurgan)}')
            if len(magnitka) > 0:
                offers.append(magnitka[0])
                magnitka.pop(0)
                print(f'M осталось {len(magnitka)}')
            if len(chelab) > 0:
                offers.append(chelab[0])
                chelab.pop(0)
                print(f'M осталось {len(chelab)}')
            print(f'offers value: {len(offers)}')
        else:
            break

    return offers

def start():
    tumen = open_file_parse('youla_tumen1.xml')
    ekat = open_file_parse('youla_ekat1.xml')
    kurgan = open_file_parse('youla_kurgan2.xml')
    magnitka = open_file_parse('youla_magn1.xml')
    chelab = open_file_parse('youla_chel_chel_obl_ufa3.xml')
    offers = unite_offers(tumen=tumen, ekat=ekat, kurgan=kurgan, magnitka=magnitka, chelab=chelab)
    print(f'All offers: {len(offers)}')
    save_list_py(offers=offers, file='youla_feed.xml')

start()
```

Если в функцию save_list_py(offers, file) передаю offers[0:100] запись проходит без ошибок, а если передаю полный список offers в котором хранится 8532 элементов, то записываются 1184 элемента, файл когда открываю, в нём почему-то эти 1184 элемента повторяются 18 раз.

Если убрать строку:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(30000)
```

то появляется вот такая ошибка:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Пример данных которые парсятся:

```
<offer id="754_4">
    <managerName>Мебель всем Тюмень</managerName>
    <phone>8 1234 12-12-12</phone>
    <address>Тюменская область, Тюмень</address>
    <youlaCategoryId>4</youlaCategoryId>
    <youlaSubCategoryId>409</youlaSubCategoryId>
    <name>Комод</name>
    <description><![CDATA[<p>✅Акционная цена до 31.10.2022г. (скидка -15%)</p><p>Комод "01"</p>
    <p ><b>Характеристики: </b></p>
    <ul><li>Тип: Комод прямой</li><li>Размер(ДхГхВ): 800х400х820мм</li><li>Цвет корпуса: Венге</li><li>Цвет фасада: Шимо светлый</li><li>Материал: ЛДСП 16мм,кромка ПВХ 0,4мм</li><li>Количество ящиков: 5</li><li>Производитель: Россия</li><li>Наличие пеленатора: Нет</li><li>Вес (+-2-3кг.): 40 кг</li><li>Опора: Цоколь</li><li>Полновыкатные Направляющие: 150р./ящик</li></ul><p>Доставка заказа по Челябинску до подъезда = 600р:
Доставка заказа по Златоусту до подъезда = 600р:
Доставка заказа по Копейску до подъезда = 900р:
Доставка заказа по Миассу и Чебаркулю до подъезда = 800р:
Доставка заказа по Кургану до подъезда = 800р:
Доставка заказа по Екатеринбургу до подъезда = 800р:
Доставка заказа по Магнитогорску и Троицку до подъезда = 800р:
Доставка заказа по Тюмени до подъезда = 800р:
Доставка заказа по Уфе до подъезда = 800р:
Подъем = 200р/этаж (на лифте 400рублей):
Сборка = 10% от стоимости:
---------------------------------------------------------------
В наличии в цветах: Венге, Бел.Дуб, Шимо Темный, Шимо Светлый, Вишня оксфорд, Белый, Серый (цвета можно сочетать)
---------------------------------------------------------------
Доставка (до подъезда)ЗА ВЕСЬ ЗАКАЗ:
По области 20 руб./км.
/// Стоимость доставки в отдаленные микрорайоны уточняйте у оператора
ЗАКАЗ:
По телефону делаете заявку.(НИКАКИХ ПРЕДОПЛАТ) Оплата производится наличными при получении, после проверки покупателем качества товара. Всё товары есть в наличии. Весь ассортимент можно посмотреть на нашем официальном сайте "mebel-vsem74"
---------------------------------------------------------------
Скидки:
за покупку мебели на сумму от 50.000руб. -5%;
за покупку от 100.000руб. -10%;
за покупку от 150.000руб. -15%.
---------------------------------------------------------------
Звоните нам с 8.00 до 22.00 (без выходных)
Для просмотра всего ассортимента перейдите на наш сайт "mebel-vsem74"
либо НИЖЕ нажмите на ИНТЕРНЕТ МАГАЗИН "Мебель-Всем74"</p> ]]></description>
        <price>4300</price>
        <picture>https://mebel-vsem74.ru/image/catalog/10_komods/Komod01(Venge+SHsv).jpg</picture>
            <picture>https://mebel-vsem74.ru/image/catalog/10_komods/Komod01(Venge+Bd).jpg</picture>
            <picture>https://mebel-vsem74.ru/image/catalog/10_komods/Komod01(SHt+SHsv).jpg</picture>
            <picture>https://mebel-vsem74.ru/image/catalog/10_komods/Komod01(SHsv).jpg</picture>
    </offer>
```

Comment: Как вы запускаете скрипт? По идее должен быть Traceback, где он?

Comment: в PyCharm запускаю

Comment: Запустите из командной строки, и покажите весь вывод.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял проблема была в том что при использовании библиотеки bs4 в каком то, месте происходила бесконечная итерация, только не могу понять в каком именно, в консоли выводит последний принт на 1184 элементе записанном в xml и прекращает работать ничего больше не выводит, появляется новая строка для записи.

Решил задачу использовав другую библиотеку.
Код поменял только в функции open_file_parse,
с этой библиотекой парсинг проходит в разы быстрее

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def open_file_parse(name_file):
    date = open(name_file, "r", encoding="utf-8")
    parser = ET.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
    tree = ET.parse(source=date, parser=parser)
    root = tree.getroot()
    offers = []
    x = 0
    for offer in root.iter('offer'):
        offer_id = offer.get('id')
        offer_manager = offer.find('managerName').text
        offer_phone = offer.find('phone').text
        offer_addres = offer.find('address').text
        offer_cat_id = offer.find('youlaCategoryId').text
        offer_sub_cat_id = offer.find('youlaSubCategoryId').text
        offer_name = offer.find('name').text
        offer_desc = offer.find('description').text
        offer_price = offer.find('price').text
        offer_picture = offer.findall('picture')
        picture = list(map(lambda x: '<picture>'+x.text+'</picture>\n', offer_picture))
        context = f'<offer id="{offer_id}">\n' \
                  f'<managerName>{offer_manager}</managerName>\n' \
                  f'<phone>{offer_phone}</phone>\n' \
                  f'<address>{offer_addres}</address>\n' \
                  f'<youlaCategoryId>{offer_cat_id}</youlaCategoryId>\n' \
                  f'<youlaSubCategoryId>{offer_sub_cat_id}</youlaSubCategoryId>\n' \
                  f'<name>{offer_name}</name>\n' \
                  f'<description><![CDATA[{offer_desc}]]></description>\n' \
                  f'<price>{offer_price}</price>\n' \
                  f'{"".join(picture)}</offer>\n'
        offers.append(context)
        x += 1
        print(f'обработано: {x}')

    date.close()
    print(f'Файл {name_file} обработан, {len(offers)} объявлений')
    return offers

def start_file():
    with open('youla_feed.xml', "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(f'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n'
                f'<yml_catalog date="2022-10-13 11:58">\n'
                f'<shop>\n<offers>\n')
    f.close()
    return print('start')

def end_file():
    with open('youla_feed.xml', "a", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(f'</offers>\n</shop>\n</yml_catalog>')
    f.close()
    return print('end')

def save_list_py(offers, file):
    f = open(file, "a", encoding='utf-8')
    x=0
    f.write("".join(offers))
    f.close()

def unite_offers(tumen, ekat, kurgan, magnitka, chelab):
    offers = []
    while True:
        if len(tumen) > 0 or len(ekat) > 0 or len(kurgan) > 0 or len(magnitka) > 0 or len(chelab) > 0:
            if len(tumen) > 0:
                offers.append(tumen[0])
                tumen.pop(0)
                print(f'Т осталось {len(tumen)}')
            if len(ekat) > 0:
                offers.append(ekat[0])
                ekat.pop(0)
                print(f'E осталось {len(ekat)}')
            if len(kurgan) > 0:
                offers.append(kurgan[0])
                kurgan.pop(0)
                print(f'K осталось {len(kurgan)}')
            if len(magnitka) > 0:
                offers.append(magnitka[0])
                magnitka.pop(0)
                print(f'M осталось {len(magnitka)}')
            if len(chelab) > 0:
                offers.append(chelab[0])
                chelab.pop(0)
                print(f'M осталось {len(chelab)}')
            print(f'offers value: {len(offers)}')
        else:
            break
    return offers

def start():
    tumen = open_file_parse('youla_tumen1.xml')
    ekat = open_file_parse('youla_ekat1.xml')
    kurgan = open_file_parse('youla_kurgan2.xml')
    magnitka = open_file_parse('youla_magn1.xml')
    chelab = open_file_parse('youla_chel_chel_obl_ufa3.xml')
    
    offers = unite_offers(tumen=tumen, ekat=ekat, kurgan=kurgan, magnitka=magnitka, chelab=chelab)
    start_file()
    save_list_py(offers=offers, file='youla_feed.xml')
    end_file()


start()
```